# Where to save updated version of a TeX Live font?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode-math

Since the release of TeX Live 2018, some fixes have been made to the Libertinus fonts (on github). Now I wonder where I have to save the new versions of the fonts so that using `fontspec` with `\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}` and using `unicode-math` with `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}` will automatically load the new versions. I tried out `usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts`, but the old versions are still loaded by default. I also saved them in `/usr/share/fonts` and in `/usr/local/share/fonts`. I want to use them globally, i.e. not include them in every LaTeX project I start.

Comment: Have you run `fc-cache` after installing them globally?

Comment: @TeXnician No, could you elaborate?

Comment: If you install a font (i.e. copy the files) the font is still not known to the system. Most operating systems do have a font cache. On Linux this can be controlled (let's say on most distros) by something like `fc-cache` which is used to update the font cache. After updating it the font is available everywhere on your system. Concerning the priority of choice (for LaTeX projects) I unfortunately don't know enough about the font loader.

Comment: If you are using xelatex you should ensure that you have only one version of the font. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to your document and then check the path and replace this fonts. With lualatex local texmf trees should imho work, but you should delete the luatex cache so that the database is recreated (but I would replace the original probably too ...).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you! Would you sind making your comment an answer and maybe explain how to clear the luatex cache?